# function returning zero sized string even when its size is not zero

Tags: c++

i am writing a function that will return the string with common prefix of all string in a given array.But i am not able to return the string as its size is still showing as zero.

```
string Solution::longestCommonPrefix(vector<string> &A) {
    string s;
    int k=A.size();
    int m=A[0].size();
    for(int i=1;i<k;i++)
    {
        int j=A[i].size();
        if(j<m) m=j;
    }
    int f;
    for(int i=0;i<k-1;i++)
    {
        for(f=0;f<m;f++)
        {
            if(A[i][f]==A[i+1][f])
            {
            s[f]=A[i][f];
            }
            else break;   
        }
        cout<<s.size();
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: That would be because it's size _is_ zero. At no point do you change its size. You have undefined behaviour in `s[f]=A[i][f]` since `s` is size zero.

Comment: i am never changing its size.i just declared a string ans passing values to it.

Comment: Can you please provide example of input and the corresponding output from the cout << s.size()

Comment: @anitashrivastava, you are modifying the contents of the `string`, however, the string is size zero. What is the final size of the string supposed to be? What's it supposed to contain?

Comment: actually,i am taking array of strings as input(eg.[abcde,abcdf,abcgh]) and outputting largest common prefix(abc)

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59803470/10686048). It explains what you are doing incorrectly, and provides two possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the size of your string, `s`, is always zero since you are never actually changing its size. The size of a string can change in a few ways, through assignment (`=`, `+=`), and `resize` being two. Your program currently has undefined behaviour, since, when you do `s[f]=A[i][f]`, you are modifying `s` at index `f`, even though `s` has no contents.

So how do you fix this? Initially, you can resize `s` to the size of `m`, and fill it temporarily with spaces. Now, there's still a logic problem in your `if` statement. Specifically, with the `else`, since if the `else` is reached, you need to cut off anything remaining, and change `m`. See the below for a full working program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string longestCommonPrefix( const vector<string> &A ) {
    string s;
    int k = A.size();
    int m = A[0].size();
    for ( int i = 1; i < k; i++ ) {
        int j = A[i].size();
        if ( j < m ) m = j;
    }
    int f;
    s.resize( m, ' ' ); // temporary, just to set the contents
    for ( int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++ ) {
        for ( f = 0; f < m; f++ ) {
            if ( A[i][f] == A[i + 1][f] ) {
                s[f] = A[i][f]; // copy the similar values
            } else {
                m = f; // if we reach a character which is not the same, then we reset m
                s.resize( m ); // and resize the string
            }
        }
    }
    return s;
}

int main() {
    vector<string> a;
    a.push_back( "hello" );
    a.push_back( "hell" );
    a.push_back( "help" );
    a.push_back( "he" );
    cout << longestCommonPrefix( a );
    getchar();
}
```

The above will have an output of `he`, which is the common prefix of all three words.

The below is a modified version of the function. First, I've replaced `int` with `size_t`, which should be used for any sizes. Second, it introduces a few error checks and simplifications. If the input `vector` is size `0`, then don't do any checks and return an empty string. If the size is `1`, then just return the contents of the element. No work needed.

After this, assume that `A[0]` is the entire prefix which belongs to all elements in the vector. In the for loop, you would then look for when this is not true, and resize the string accordingly. You will notice that the loop starts at `1`, since we are assuming the first element is the full prefix. The inner loop also is less than `s.size()`, so that as `s` shrinks, it is accounted for.

```
string longestCommonPrefix( const vector<string> &A ) {
    size_t k = A.size();
    if ( k == 0 )
        return "";
    if ( k == 1 )
        return A[0];

    string s = A[0];
    for ( size_t i = 1; i < k - 1; i++ ) {
        if ( A[i].size() < s.size() ) s.resize( A[i].size() );
        for ( size_t f = 0; f < s.size(); f++ ) {
            if ( A[i][f] != A[i + 1][f] ) {
                s.resize( f );
            }
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

EDIT: There was an issue in the second version, with going out of bounds. UB again (oops). I added in a check, inside the first `for` loop, which now resizes `s` if it is larger than `A[i]`

Answer (score 0):

You're indexing into a string that's uninitialized.  When you do `s[f]=A[i][f];`, you're actually introducing Undefined Behavior into the mix - you might be writing to the string's memory or over something else entirely.  No matter the behavior, you aren't triggering any of the string's internal counters that the C++ class exposes for you.

Instead, try doing `s += A[i][f]`.  `std::string` exposes the `+=` operator for you to append characters to an existing string.  You can read about that and much more that your `std::string` can do here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: `s += A[i][f]` will certainly get rid of the undefined behaviour, and the size 0, but it will produce very incorrect output.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned there is undefined behaviour at `s[f]=A[i][f];` and also gave implementations, however Here is another version for c++14 or above with `stl` algorithms,

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<numeric>
#include<vector>


std::string longest_common_prefix(const std::vector<std::string>& v) {
    if (v.size() == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    auto begin = std::begin(v[0]), end = std::end(v[0]);
    end = std::accumulate(std::begin(v) + 1, std::end(v), end, [begin](auto end, const auto& s) {
        return std::mismatch(begin, end, std::begin(s), std::end(s)).first;
    });
    return std::string(begin, end);
}
```